# Network stopped working on Ubuntu after system had locked up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, troubleshooting, networkmanager

My main PC has AN Athlon X2 4600+ on an Asus M2npv-vm. Has been working fine for ages running Ubuntu. Today it the system locked up and I had to do a reset. Since then it will not connect to the router or cable modem. I can connect another PC to the router, so that looks okay.

What can I do to test the network connection from Ubuntu? It's not even getting an IP.

I suppose it could be something has died in the hardware, but want to eliminate other possibilities first.

Comment: what does the output of "ifconfig" say ? Also, try "sudo dhclient eth0" where eth0 is the interface name.

Answer (score 5):

Got it working using the following sequence of commands. Use sudo on all

```
service network-manager stop
rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
service network-manager start
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me multiple times (Ubuntu 9.10,10.04,10.10 + Gnome):

- Right-click on network icon at gnome panel
- Turn "Network" on.

For some reason, network is switched off on system crash or non-clean poweroff. Removing NetworkManager.state file as Steve suggests also does the trick, as default state with everything "on" is used.